# VBA Insertar vía ADODB a XLSX

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy usando este codigo VBA para insertar en una tabla, lo hace, pero dejando varios registros en blanco:

```
Dim oCn   As Object
Set oCn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oCn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
         "Data Source=C:\db_VBA_ODBC\usuarios.xlsx;" & _
         "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
oCn.Execute "Insert Into [Usuarios$] (Userid,Name) Values(1,'Bob')"
oCn.Close
```

¿a que se debe?

Comment: Lo has conseguido solucionar? @LuisArnaldoMataFigueroa

Comment: No lo hice, tube que descartar el XLSx, muchos problemas, opté por base de datos.